# WPF Binding to specific property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm new to DataBinding but would like to accomplish the following:

I have a ViewModel which has a collection of objects: `CollectionOfStuff`

Each object `Stuff` has some properties: `Name`, `Value`.

In my View, I have a `StackPanel` with some `TextBlock`s. I would like to bind the TextBlock's `Text` property to a specific property. ( I would like to bind to `Value` when `Name` of `Stuff` is "some name" )

On my `StackPanel` I have set the `DataContext` to the collection.

However for the textblocks, when I try ... `Text="{Binding Path=Value"}` ... I only get the first object in the `CollectionOfStuff`. How do I selectively bind to the `Value` of an object when the `Name` is "some name" ?

Comment: Is "some name" specific for each Textbox?

Comment: yeah for example a TextBlock will be the title, so I basically want the Value of the Stuff object where the Name = "Title"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I **THINK**, from your description, you want to use an ItemsControl, which is backed by a StackPanel by default.  It will show all of your items with the given template (I included a very simple one).  It would look like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfStuff}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Is that what you want to do?  If so, ignore the rest.

**If, however,** you are looking to bind to a specific item in the list, you will need to make sure that CollectionOfStuff implents a `this[string index]` indexer (very important step).  Then, you can call it out by name:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding CollectionOfStuff['theName']}"></StackPanel>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Value}" />
</StackPanel>
```

If you are going that route, but you don't have control of the type of collection that `CollectionOfStuff` is, then you can always create your own indexer on your ViewModel:

```
public object this[string indexer]
{
    get
    {
        return CollectionOfStuff.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == indexer);
    }
}
```

Then, your DataContext on your StackPanel would look like this: `DataContext="{Binding ['theName']}"`

I suppose it all depends on what, exactly, you are trying to do.  Your solution is in this answer some place :)